# Elixir: Generating list names programmatically

Tags: elixir

In Elixir I want to create a variable number of lists, which start out identical. And I want to name then programmatically, e.g.

LIST1 = 1,2,3

LIST2 = 1,2,3 etc

The coding approach I am trying is as follows. Can this be done in Elixir or is it verboten?

```
n = IO.gets("Enter number of lists: ") |> String.trim_trailing
n = String.to_integer(n)

generatelistnames(n,1)

def generatelistnames(0,0), do: nil
def generatelistnames(numberofnodes,1) do
if (numberofnodes < 1) do
   loop(0,1)
 else
    listname = "LIST"+Integer.to_string(numberofnodes)
    listname = [1,2,3]
    IO.puts "#{listname}"
    loop(numberofnodes-1,1)
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think it's forbidden but I think using [Comprehensions](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html) may be a better approach to this sort of application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question in essence is about generating a list and providing some naming to those lists. I assume that the naming of those lists is purely UI related, e.g. the user inputs a number, a few lists get created and each list is printed out with a name.

In such a case, then in general, when programming you need to separate your concerns. There is the concern of generating a list and there is the concern of UI.

In your pseudo code approach, you are trying to tackle both problems at the same time, instead you may consider something like this:

```
defmodule MyList do 
  def generate(amount) do
    1..amount
    |> Enum.map(fn e -> 
       # Keep track of the number and produce a list. Currently the list produced is simply hardcoded, but you can modify in any way you want.
      {e, produce_a_list()}
    end)
  end

  def run do
    3
    |> generate()
    |> output()
  end

  defp output(lists) do
    lists
    |> Enum.each(fn {nr, a_list} -> 
      IO.inspect("LIST_#{nr}: ")
      IO.inspect(a_list)
    end)  
  end

  # Replace in any way you want to create the list, randomly or by some previously generated list ....
  defp produce_a_list do
    [1,2,3,4]
  end
end
```

To see an example, you can run it like this:
`MyList.run`
which will render you something like this:

```
"LIST_1"
[1, 2, 3, 4]
"LIST_2"
[1, 2, 3, 4]
"LIST_3"
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Once I have the lists I need to be able to address them individually so I can add/remove entries from them, but once created they are treated differently. So I need to be able to say, for example, List.delete_at(LIST_1,3)

Comment: In such a case, you will need to create a map where the keys are represented by the names of the various lists(LIST_1, ...) and where its values are occupied by those list contents respectively. Whenever the user provides you with an input, you look up the list by its name inside that map. In order to manage state, you either use a genserver, either you write it to disk.